# Non-unique C++ unsorted intersection algorithm

Tags: c++, intersection

I have been trying to come up with a way to write an efficient algorithm to perform an unsorted intersection on two vectors/arrays, but with no luck.  I am working with one large non-unique array (generally 500,000 to 1,000,000 values), and one relatively smaller (maybe 5000 values max) unique array.

I have seen a variety of methods suggested on here involving techniques such as unordered_sets, but to my understanding, this doesn't work if one of the arrays is non-unique.  Secondly, instead of having an output vector that contains the numbers common to both arrays, I'd like to have the output vector contain the indices of those common values with respect to the larger array.  So, if the larger array has 5 locations that equal one of the values in the smaller array, I need each of those 5 indices.  Perhaps something similar to python's in1d function.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Regarding the non-unique side, could you please clarify what would be an intersection of `{1,2,2,3}` and `{2,3}`?

Comment: Sure.  {1,2,3} would be the indices of the elements in {1,2,2,3} intersected by {2,3}

Comment: what's your values? can they be effectively hashed?

Comment: The values of both arrays are just arbitrary integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the unique side into an `unordered_set`, and go through the non-unique side one by one. If you find an item at `non_unique_side[i]` in the `unordered_set(unique_side)`, add `i` to the result.

Assuming that `unordered_set` is implemented as a hash set with `O(1)` amortized insertion and lookup times, this algorithm gets you `O(L+S)` time complexity, where `L` is the number of items in the larger list, and `S` is the number of items in the smaller set. This is as fast as you can do an intersection.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create another vector that contains all the indexes from the big array. Then sort the indexes using a predicate that uses one level of indirection, and either do the same for the unique array or sort it in place. Then do a normal ordered intersection using a comparison that allows for one level of indirection and places the index from the mapping vector into the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the large array from its value to int.

for example: `unordered_map<int,int>`

When you map the larger array, just increase the value for each item you find

Then you just need to go over the smaller value, and for each value, check if it exists in the map. If it exists, then add the number of items in the mapped int to the result vector.

so if you have 5 sixes, the map[6] = 5.. so just add 5 instances of 6 to the result value.

Edit:

If you want indices, you can map to a vector of int, and keep for each value the vector of indices you've found.

Comment: From the response to my comment it looks like the OP is looking for indexes of items from the non-unique side, rather than the values themselves.

Comment: That's not a problem, you can map to a vector of indices.